# (Randomly?) find an amount by summing a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, numerical

I have a 2D array with :

- an index,
- a numerical value

When I sum this 2D array I get an amount (let's say "a").

I am provided with another amount  (let's say "b", a <> b , and b is the target) and the granularity isn't fine enough to segregate one row from another.

The idea here is to try to find all the rows that compose b and discard the others.

What I am trying to do is building a script that (randomly ?) select rows and sum them until it approches (reduce the distance) the targeted sum.

I was first thinking about trying to start at a random point and from there try to sum each combination of rows and keep adding them up until
-> I have something close enough
or
-> the number of set iteration is over (1 million ?)

... but with the number of rows involved this won't fit in memory.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Basically you are trying to solve the subset sum problem.

Comment: it looks like a problem of dynamic programming , brute force is bad solution, if only your array not small enouth

Comment: Although it wasn't specified it's real numbers (positive, negative, floats) and I don't have more that 600 000 rows.

Comment: Brute force solution would take on the order of the universe exploding to finish. Would an approximation be okay? There are really good approximations to NP-Complete problems that often get exact solutions.

Comment: @AndyG I guess in the subset pbm we need to compute each combinations and find the best solution, here one solution is ok (not the best), maybe I can try to split my search space in 2 ( >1 and <0) and test if b>0 , if true I look into the + search space, compute the distance to b for each row and find the minimum distance to b. If distance (d)> 0, I compute the distribution on the negative search space and find one area that approaches d ... With an acceptable |d|<10 . I'm worried about gravitating around |d|<10 if it keeps moving between the + and - search space while trying to minimize d